# Has Minecraft 1.16.20x moved the storage location?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

It seems with the recent Minecraft 1.16.200 and .201 updates, there's no longer the option to store worlds externally. I can't seem to find that option, which I need to restore my son's worlds to his new device. He's very attached to them, and I can't find a good option.

I've already backed up the worlds from his old device onto a laptop, but moving them to the new device does nothing. The old device doesn't have the worlds anymore. I've done this several times over the years on a number of devices, so I didn't think twice this time.

I don't have root access on this new device. Is there a way I could use ADB to inject the old worlds into the app folder in the correct place or anything else? How can I restore his worlds from my laptop?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just go to the `minecraftWorlds` folder? Nothing has changed

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 really? It does on iOS and Windows 10, is there an android equivalent?

Comment: @Penguin Based off of [this article.](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131551-Where-are-Minecraft-files-stored-)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 That article only states where the base Minecraft files are stored. What makes you think there is no `minecraftWorlds` folder inside that?

Comment: @Penguin Whoops, I forgot that was the case. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Penguin I've accessed that folder, and it doesn't work for me anymore. I've backed up that folder, and moved worlds across devices for years. But I can't get it to work anymore... It seems to have changed after that update?